# Ansible wait_for_connection until the hosts are ready for ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to configure some VM's.

Problem I am facing right now is, I can't execute ansible commands right after the VM's are just started, it gives `connection time out` error. This happens when I execute the ansible right after the VMs are spinned up in `GCP`.

Commands working fine when I execute ansible playbook after 60 seconds, but I am looking for a way to do this automatically without manually wait 60s and execute, so I can execute right after VM's are spun up and ansible will wait until they are ready. **I don't want to add a delay seconds to ansible tasks as well**,

I am looking for a dynamic way where ansible tries to execute playbook and when it fails, it won't show any error but wait until the VM's are ready?

I used this, but it still doesn't work (as it fails)

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Wait for connection
      wait_for_connection: # but this will still fails, am I doing this wrong?

    - name: Ping all hosts for connectivity check
      ping:
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you please explain precisely what is  "failing" and how when you use `wait_for_connection` ? Note: if you don't want add a delay/retry/timeout, how is ansible going to know when to stop waiting in case of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my side.
I've fixed this with this task [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html).
The basic way is to wait for an ssh connection like this :

```
- name: Wait 300 seconds for port 22 to become open and contain "OpenSSH"
  wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: '{{ (ansible_ssh_host|default(ansible_host))|default(inventory_hostname) }}'
    search_regex: OpenSSH
    delay: 10
  connection: local
```

I guess your VM must launch an application/service so you can monitor on the vm in the log file where application is started, like this for example (here for nexus container):

```
- name: Wait container is start and running
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ ansible_nexus_user }}"
  wait_for:
    path: "{{ ansible_nexus_directory_data }}/log/nexus.log"
    search_regex: ".*Started Sonatype Nexus.*"
```

Comment: Can you please explain precisely what is wrong with `wait_for_connection` and for which reason you had to use this workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is to postpone `gather_facts` until the server is up, as that otherwise will time out as you experienced. Your file could work as follows:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Wait for connection (600s default)
      ansible.builtin.wait_for_connection:

    - name: Gather facts manually
      ansible.builtin.wait_for_connection
```

I have these under `pre_tasks` instead of `tasks`, but it should probably work if they are first in your file.